# Why is F# suddenly returning values from functions as @+ the line number?

Tags: .net, f#

I have some code in F# that was working fine, but now any function returns the name of the let binding with @ + line number?  So before when I did something like this:

```
let sqlData = GetSummary 2011
```

I would get the data.  Now I get sqlData@160 as the return type, which break other functions expecting a specific type.  Any help as to why this suddenly started happening would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
So I changed the GetSummary code to this just to see what would happen:

```
 let GetSummary fiscalYear =
    let g = 22
    g
```

And nothing changed.  I got the exact same results and it would not break in the function even though I have a breakpoint.  It also would not step into GetSummary either.  Why would it ignore the some functions and not others?

Comment: Can you post the code for GetSummary?

Comment: My guess is that it started inferring different types from what you expect and those types are propogating through your program in surprising ways.

Comment: Get Summary calls a few other functions that return data from SQL Server, plus a custom type.  Even other basic functions are not returning properly, then other ones will.  I'm not sure why.
Gabe, no it is not inferring the type incorrectly, it is changing the return type to sqlData@160, which does not exist.
The odd thing is that it won't step through the GetSummary function.  It's like it's placing a bookmark for the code.  Lazy execution gone bad?

Comment: Post the entire code on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and link to it. _Something_ is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now I feel really stupid.  I went back and realized that I had changed the definition of GetSummary to

```
GetSummary name fiscalYear
```

Since I was not passing in the name, it thought that I was currying the function, hence the odd behavior.

Thanks for your input!!!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you've changed something in the `GetSummary` function, so that it actually returns a function instead of returning the data (when you give it a single argument). For example, this snippet behaves a bit similarly - it returns some internal things and it doesn't step inside the `bar` function:

```
> let bar n = printfn "inside bar"; n + 1;;
val bar : int -> int

> let foo n = bar;; // This takes 'n' and returns a function..
val foo : 'a -> (int -> int)

> printfn "%O" (foo 10);; // Here, we call 'foo', but the result is a function!
FSI_0016+it@15-3
```

Comment: Tomas, it's possible, but if you see my edit above, I changed the function and got the same behavior.  Is the compiler not recompiling?  I'm getting really stumped!